# Conditionally Transpose excel data

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an excel file where I have some country specific information. I need to transpose it in a way so that for each country I can get the data populated in rows. Example:

Source Data:

```
Column A             Column B        Column C 
-----------------+---------------+------------------+ 
United Kingdom       Data 1          Instruction 1 
United Kingdom       Data 2          Instruction 2 
United Kingdom       Data 3          Instruction 3 
USA                  Data 4          Instruction 4 
USA                  Data 5          Instruction 5 
India                Data 6          Instruction 6 
UAE                  Data 7          Instruction 7 
UAE                  Data 8          Instruction 8
```

Expected Output

```
Column A             Column B          Column C           Column D  
----------------+-------------------+------------------+-------------------+     
United Kingdom       Data 1            Data 2             Data 3 
United Kingdom       Instruction 1     Instruction 2      Instruction 3  
USA                  Data 4            Data 5  
USA                  Instruction 4     Instruction 5 
India                Data 6 
India                Instruction 6 
UAE                  Data 7            Data 8 
UAE                  Instruction 7     Instruction 8
```

Please note that I have data for 242 countries in my source table and they have data elements anywhere from 1 to 20 in count.

Can someone please suggest a formula or a macro script to help me do this. I am not an expert in excel I have a vlookup degree in it but not beyond it :).

Hope I have not made it too confusing. :)

Comment: Check other questions that may guide you on your coding, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63784574/excel-how-do-i-split-a-single-row-with-currencies-into-multiple-rows-in-excel/63785529#63785529

Comment: It can be done with out VBA, but it gets a little ugly on the formula side.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns why does it NEED VBA code?  I agreed that it can be done much cleaner in VBA.

Comment: @ForwardEd To make it in a single step. Manually can be done, like everything in Excel, but with VBA can be done faster

Answer (score 2):

Given your example, where your source data consists of three columns, you can do this using Power Query, available in Excel 2010+

In Excel 2016+ with your cursor in the Source table:  *(not sure about starting this in earlier versions)*

- `Data-->Get&Transform-->From Table/Range`
- When the Power Query UI opens, go to `Home/Advanced Editor`

  - Replace the code you see with the M-Code below
  - Change the Table Name on the second line of code to reflect the table name generated for your Source Data
- Close and Load to a new page, or to a different spot on the same page
- If you select each of the Applied Steps in turn, you can see the step-by-step modifications made and understand how this was done.

**M-Code**

```
let
    //Replace Table Name in line below with your REAL table name
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Column A", type text}, {"Column B", type text}, {"Column C", type text}}),
    #"Unpivoted Other Columns" = Table.UnpivotOtherColumns(#"Changed Type", {"Column A"}, "Attribute", "Value"),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Unpivoted Other Columns",{"Attribute"}),
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Inserted Modulo" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Index", "Modulo", each Number.Mod([Index], 2), type number),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Modulo",{"Index"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns1", {"Column A", "Modulo"}, {{"Grouped", each _, type table [Column A=nullable text, Value=text, Modulo=number]}}),
    #"Removed Columns2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows",{"Modulo"}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Removed Columns2", "D/I", each Table.Column([Grouped],"Value")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "colCt", each List.Count([#"D/I"])),
        
        maxCols = List.Max(#"Added Custom1"[colCt]),
    
    #"Extracted Values" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Custom1", 
            {"D/I", each Text.Combine(List.Transform(_, Text.From), ";"), type text}),
    #"Removed Columns3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Extracted Values",{"Grouped", "colCt"}),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.SplitColumn(#"Removed Columns3", "D/I", 
            Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(";", QuoteStyle.Csv), maxCols)
in
    #"Split Column by Delimiter"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through a series of steps, and I had to use a helper column.  This solution also requires that the countries be grouped together as in your example.  To achieve that last bit, just sort your data by country name first and that will ensure it is.

The formulas you see are assuming your data is in A2:A9 with row 1 being blank or a header row.  Its important that whatever information is in the header row, it is not a match for any of the names in the unique list.

## Step 1 - Unique List of Country Names

You can either use the built in function under the data tab in the data tools section called Remove Duplicate and generate a list in an empty column.  This is your helper column.

[image]

Alternatively you can use the following formula.  It is an array formula so when you enter it you need need to press <kbd>CONTROL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> instead of just <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.  You will know you have done it right when { } appear around your formula in the formula bar.  Note you cannot add these manually for the formula. Also you will need to have a blank cell above where you plan to start the list.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$9, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($G$1:G1, $A$2:$A$9), 0)),"")
```

Copy that cell down until you are seeing empty cells

## Step 2 - Set up Country Names for Output

Since every country requires has to be listed twice, generate a list from the unique list that was just created, but only advance down the list every second row.  Assuming your unique list was generated in G2:G9 You can achieve this as follows:

```
=INDEX(G:G,INT((ROW(A1)-1)/2)+ROW($G$2))
```

Place the above formula where you want your table to start and copy down until you are seeing empty cells.

## Step 3 - Fill In Data

Now that you have your two row country name list, in the cell to the right of the top most entry, enter the following formula and copy down and to the right.  Copy as far to the right as you have maximum entries for any of the countries, so in your case 20 columns to the right.  Copy down to the bottom of your table.

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$9,$G2)>=COLUMNS($H$2:H2),INDEX($B$2:$C$9,MATCH($G2,$A$2:$A$9,0)+COLUMNS($H$2:H2)-1,COUNTIF($G$2:G2,$G2)),"")
```

[image: POC]