# Excel - How do I split a single row with currencies into multiple rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following data:

```
Product           GBP        USD        EUR         CAD
----------------------------------------------------------
Adidas Shoe       8         30         25           25 
Puma Shoe         7         40         30           25
```

How do I split the data into the following, in Excel 2020? Using a macro?

```
Product           VALUE     CURRENCYISO
----------------------------------------------------------
Adidas Shoe       8          GBP
Adidas Shoe       30         USD
Adidas Shoe       25         EUR
Adidas Shoe       25         CAD
Puma Shoe         7          GBP
Puma Shoe         40         USD
Puma Shoe         30         EUR
Puma Shoe         25         CAD
```

Comment: Just in case you don't know since you're new. If you like an answer and it works for you can you accept it by clicking the tick underneath the vote on the answer. This lets everyone know that you've received a good answer and the question is essentially closed.

Comment: The keyword to look for is *"unpivot"*: [Quick Ways to Unpivot Excel Data](https://contexturesblog.com/archives/2016/08/18/quick-ways-unpivot-excel-data/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest one, but can help:

```
Dim MiMatriz As Variant
Dim i As Long, ZZ As Long
Dim MyRow As Long


MiMatriz = Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value

'type row number where data is going to be pasted. HEaders will be one row over
MyRow = 10

Range("A" & MyRow - 1).Value = "Product"
Range("B" & MyRow - 1).Value = "Value"
Range("C" & MyRow - 1).Value = "Currency ISO"


'we start array at 2 because first index got headers
For i = 2 To UBound(MiMatriz) Step 1
    For ZZ = 2 To 5 Step 1 'your range got 5 columns of data
        Range("A" & MyRow).Value = MiMatriz(i, 1) 'product
        Range("B" & MyRow).Value = MiMatriz(i, ZZ) 'value
        Range("C" & MyRow).Value = MiMatriz(1, ZZ) 'header
        MyRow = MyRow + 1
    Next ZZ
Next i

Erase MiMatriz
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure they're probably a better way to do it but I have one solution here:

```
Sub TransposeData()

Dim lastrow As Long, lastcolumn As Long, ws As Worksheet, irow As Long, icolumn As Long, lrowout As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'your sheet name
lastrow = ws.Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change "F" to product list
lastcolumn = ws.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'Change "4" to the row with the headers

For irow = 5 To lastrow 'what row number does the data start from (exluding headers)
    For icolumn = 7 To lastcolumn 'what column number does the data start from (exluding product names)
        lrowout = ws.Range("R" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Change "R" to column output will be in
        ws.Range("R" & lrowout + 1).Value = ws.Range("F" & irow).Value 'Change "R" to where your product name will be
        ws.Range("S" & lrowout + 1).Value = ws.Cells(irow, icolumn).Value 'Change "S" to where value will be
        ws.Range("T" & lrowout + 1).Value = ws.Cells(4, icolumn).Value 'Change "T" to where currency will be
    Next icolumn
Next irow

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: And if you want it to be for a specific range, not to the last row then change `lastrow` to the last row you want on the `For irow` line, and do the same for `lastcolumn` in the `For icolumn` line.

Comment: All your `Integer` variables need to be of type `Long` Excel has more rows than `Integer` can handle!